# Insert data into remote database table from local database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a problem, I use SQL Server 2014. I need to copy data from a local table to the identical table on a remote server. Right now, I can only insert static data to the remote table, select data from the remote table, but I didn't get to do what I want.

Here's my sql code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE ##TempTable

CREATE TABLE ##TempTable 
(
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [ARXUrl] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO ##TempTable 
    SELECT 
        [Name], [Description], [ARXUrl], [IsDeleted], [CreatedDate]
    FROM [dbo].[ARXSystem]
GO

-- destination database
:SETVAR remoteDB [slic-test]
:CONNECT someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 -U user -P password
--source database
USE [SLIC]
GO 

SELECT * 
FROM ##TempTable;

INSERT INTO $(remoteDB).[dbo].[ARXSystem]
    SELECT * 
    FROM #TempTable
GO
```

and here is the message I received

> (1 row(s) affected)
>   Connecting to someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 as SLIC...
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 22
>   Invalid object name '##TempTable'.
>   Disconnecting connection from someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 as SLIC...

Comment: You are trying to SELECT data from a temp table in the destination before you create that table.  You need to create the table first and insert the data.  temp tables don't persist.  also, your last select is missing a #

Comment: its not even a temp table. The statement used is to create a permenant table

Comment: @Takarii How is a global temp table permanent?  They are visible to everyone, and are deleted when all connections that have referenced them have closed.  But in this case I don't see a need for a global temp table, just use a regular temporary table.

Comment: @RickS why would you need a permenant temp table? I have assumed this is all nested within a transaction. This way you dont need to dispose of a table each time

Comment: thanks, but when I open connect to remote server, I have lose connection with local server and with all selected data. Is it mean that in management studio I can't open more then one connection to the sql servers?

Comment: --destinition database
:SETVAR remoteDB [slic-test]
:CONNECT someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 -U user -P password
--source database
SELECT * FROM $(remoteDB).[dbo].ARXSystem;

:SETVAR localDB [slic]
:CONNECT PC\SQLEXPRESS -U user -P password

SELECT * FROM $(localDB).[dbo].ARXSystem;

Comment: and result "Connecting to someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 as SLIC...
Disconnecting connection from someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014 as SLIC...
Connecting to PC\SQLEXPRESS as sa...
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid object name 'slic-test.dbo.ARXSystem'.
Disconnecting connection from PC\SQLEXPRESS as sa..."

Comment: @Takarii - Temp tables do not persist after broken/terminated connections.  Once your session terminates and reconnects to the remote server your data is gone.  You can't really nest a connection change like this into a database transaction.  You need to use Openrowset or openquery.

Comment: @BradD I understand. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use remote server via Openquery or Openrowset, which might require a server configuration change on the source system where the query is executed.  To push the data from the source to target the query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
'Server=someserver.net\SQLEXPRESS2014;User=xxxx;Password=xxxx;',
'SELECT [Name], [Description], [ARXUrl], [IsDeleted], [CreatedDate]
FROM [slic-test].[dbo].[ARXSystem]')
SELECT [Name], [Description], [ARXUrl], [IsDeleted], [CreatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[ARXSystem]
```

OPENROWSET documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: Seems it working with simple example. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note: for SQLNCLI11 you have to use UID and PWD instead of user and password.

Answer (score -2):

Your SQL Creates a table, but its not a temporary table. It will create it in the active database. You need to use something like

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE 
   (
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [ARXUrl] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
   )
```

Then after your switch databases you can refer to that table using

```
 INSERT INTO $(remoteDB).[dbo].[ARXSystem]
             SELECT * FROM @temptable
 GO
```

Hopefully this will help