# Push data to another SQL server

Tags: sql-server

A C# program runs a SQL command on localhost and inserts 4 rows in a localhost\default\DB\tblSN.

There are about 10 localhosts each runs one instance of the C# program and so, 10 local SQL instances. Each SQL instance therefore has a table called tblSN that the C# command once executed adds 4 lines of data to.

My question is, how can I push those 4 rows from 10 local SQL instances of tblSN onto one centralized SQL instance? My goal is to view all the data scattered along 10 local SQL instances in just one local database.

Comment: frankly, I can think of just one solution, which is linked servers. But that's out of my reach as I don't have admin rights on the centralized server. So, I'm looking into some kind of command like approach

Comment: What has your research shown up as options?

Comment: thank you, Dale for pointing that out. I'll try to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370660/insert-data-into-remote-database-table-from-local-database-table

Comment: An ETL type solution that you might implement to populate a data warehouse would seem appropriate, various methods are possible depending on various requirements around realtime or not, concurrent or not etc

Comment: If you really only need to view the data and not store a copy, you can register all the instances in a group in SSMS.  Open a new query on the group and then run the select on all instances at once.  It would require using the same exact query.  It's very limited.  Might be enough in some cases.  There is no global order by across connections - fastest result sets are first.

Comment: Thank you, Randy in Marin! This might help in the future

Comment: Why don't you just have one central SQL Server?

Comment: Thank you, Charlieface for the question! That's not a choice of mine, rather restrictions. By the way, the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370660/insert-data-into-remote-database-table-from-local-database-table worked out quite well

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in what's the answer, I used this approach
[Insert data into remote database table from local database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370660/insert-data-into-remote-database-table-from-local-database-table)
and managed to solve the problem